# Print out the contents of a string using ROS_INFO

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a line such as:

```
   std_msgs::String s;
s.data = c.c_str(); //same data as above.
pthread_mutex_lock(&send_CS);
tum_ardrone_pub.publish(s);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&send_CS);
```

What I would like to do is look at the contents of s that is passed into the method publish(). I tried something like:

```
ROS_INFO("(2) (%s) \n",s.c_str());
```

But that failed at compile time. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/108646/print-out-the-contents-of-a-string-using-ros_info/) by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2013-12-09

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`std_msgs::String` is *not* the same thing as `std::string` and cannot be treated as such; it is a message type that has a `std::string` member variable called `data`. Thus, the correct way to output the message string is

`ROS_INFO("%s\n", s.data.c_str());`

---

Originally posted by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) with karma: 1951 on 2013-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 13

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on 2013-12-09**:
Thank you!

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2013-12-12**:
For additional clarification, using ROS_INFO_STREAM uses the ostream operator implementation (operator<<) that rosmsg generates for each message type.  The ostream operator is similar to the output you would see from rostopic echo.

**Comment by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on 2013-12-12**:
Thanks for that!

**Comment by [Combinacijus](https://answers.ros.org/users/44007/combinacijus/) on 2022-12-14**:
For some reason `c_str()` didn't work for me so I used `data()` instead: `ROS_INFO("frame: %s", msg.header.frame_id.data());` or in OP case `ROS_INFO("%s\n", s.data());`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tend to use ROS_INFO_STREAM when I'm doing simple debugging.

You should be able to do:

ROS_INFO_STREAM(s);

Or

ROS_INFO_STREAM("Msg: " << s);

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2013-12-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on 2013-12-09**:
This is useful, thanks!

**Comment by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on 2021-06-18**:
I tried this for `moveit_msgs/RobotTrajectory.msg` and it worked fine. And I think it can print any type of ROS message. Thanks!